# Hive and Sqoop partition

Tags: hadoop, hive, sqoop, sqoop2

I have sqoopd data from Netezza table and output file is in HDFS, but one column is a timestamp and I want to load it as a date column in my hive table. Using that column I want to create partition on date. How can i do that?

Example: in HDFS data is like = 2013-07-30 11:08:36

In hive I want to load only date (2013-07-30) not timestamps. I want to partition on that column DAILY.

How can I pass partition by column as dynamically?

I have tried with loading data into one table as source. In final table I will do insert overwrite table partition by (date_column=dynamic date) select * from table1

Answer (score 0):

Set these 2 properties -

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;
```

And the Query can be like -

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE TABLE PARTITION (DATE_STR)
SELECT 
  :
  :
 -- Partition  Col is the last column 
  to_date(date_column) DATE_STR
FROM table1;
```

You can explore the two options of hive-import - if it is an [incremental import](http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports) you will be able to get the current day's partition.

```
--hive-partition-key    
--hive-partition-value
```

Comment: Hi,Thanks for ur info.I have tried to_date(daye_column) ...partition col is the last column to_date(date_column) date_str from table1..but it not working.its giving parse exception to_date(col_name)

Comment: instead of insert overwrite is there any way to write only new or updated columns..not to re-write all all the data again in table

Comment: Possibly the dates are not well formed - check the task-tracker logs. 

Sqoop Has this option of incremental imports -
http://sqoop.apache.org/docs/1.4.3/SqoopUserGuide.html#_incremental_imports

You can expplore the two options of hive-import - if it is an incremental import you will be able to get the current day's partition.
--hive-partition-key 
--hive-partition-value

Answer (score 0):

You can just load the EMP_HISTORY table from EMP by enabling dynamic partition and converting the timestamp to date using [to_date](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF) date function

The code might look something like this....

```
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition=true;
SET hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode=nonstrict;

INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE EMP_HISTORY PARTITION (join_date)
    SELECT e.name as name, e.age as age, e.salay as salary, e.loc as loc, to_date(e.join_date) as join_date from EMP e ;
```